# There is no WiFi signal when debugging app

Tags: wi-fi

I'm using a real device to build code with IntelliJ.
I realized that when I run app, the WiFi signal is too weak, almost lost the connection.
My device is Xiaomi Redmi note 5. The WiFi only loses the connection when I run the app or debug the app. If anyone has same problem, please tell me, lost internet connection and I can't run the app and test it.

Comment: If you build another app, does the problem still occur? In other words, is this caused by your app in particular?

Comment: Based on more than 1-year experience in developing and debugging Android apps, I've never experienced this. Android emulator can throttle network, but AFAIK it can't do that on real devices. Since you're developing an app, you should check the logcat if there's something related to the WiFi when you debug/run your app.

Comment: I got it, just turn off terminal and turn on again :)))

Comment: @HuệVũ feel free to put that as an answer to your question if that was your solution